# [Android][cyanogenmod 12.0] Source syncing 403 error

Tags: android, git, github, cyanogenmod, repo

I am syncing sources of cm12 but facing some problem like
1. I am using repo sync -f command for syncing
it shows syncing complete but most of the folders are missing as vendor,device,platform prebuilts and packages but they appeared in the .repo folder
there are some errors when it is syncing packages

`*Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_UnifiedEmail
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_UnifiedEmail/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed**`*

I tried to solve this by changing the manifest.xml but no success
how to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem fetching CM9. Following the advice found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20944676&postcount=6), particularly the use of `repo sync -j1`, I was able to isolate the problem to android_external_svox, which was taken down due to a DMCA violation. I went back to the original manifest.xml file, edited out that one line, and the sync finished without error. more details [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224201002/http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Comment_download-source-code-for-Galaxy_Tab_(CDMA)).